# How to prevent zsh from storing "up" commands to history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

For example, say I do a command like `appbuild` by hitting `up arrow` ten times in a row. Now, if I want to go back to the last unique command before that, I have to hit `up` ten times in a row.

Any way to change this preference? IIRC Bash did not do this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [`setopt hist_ignore_dups`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HIST_005fIGNORE_005fDUPS). The equivalent bash setting was `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:…`. If you had `HISTCONTROL=erasedups`, the zsh equivalent is [`setopt hist_ignore_all_dups`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HIST_005fIGNORE_005fALL_005fDUPS).

On a related note, the zsh equivalent to putting `ignorespace` in `HISTCONTROL` is [`setopt hist_ignore_space`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HIST_005fIGNORE_005fSPACE).

`setopt` commands, like other interactive configurations for zsh, go into `~/.zshrc` (i.e. the file called `.zshrc` in your home directory).